# What bad things would happen if `std::ostringstream` had an `operator <<` which returns `std::ostringstream &`?

Tags: c++, c++11, stream, std, c++98

In some languages like Ruby, there is fancy syntax for creating formatted output
as a "one-liner" in part because of how commonly this is needed in Ruby applications.

It's also commonly needed in some C++ applications. Here's some example code:

```
if (num_doggies > num_biscuits) {
  std::ostringstream ss;
  ss << "There are " << num_doggies" << " puppy dogs and only " << num_biscuits << " biscuits!";
  log_warn(ss.str());
  this->negotiate_biscuit_reduction();
}
```

---

Some open source C++98 projects have a workaround that looks like this:

```
struct string_formatter {
  std::ostringstream ss;

  template <typename T>
  string_formatter & operator << (const T & t) {
    ss << t;
    return *this;
  }

  operator std::string() const {
    return ss.str();
  }
};
```

So that they can write something like this:

```
if (num_doggies > num_biscuits) {
  log_warn(string_formatter{} << "There are " << num_doggies" << " puppy dogs and only " << num_biscuits << " biscuits!");
  this->negotiate_biscuit_reduction();
}
```

turning three lines into one line.

However, the `string_formatter` class looks fairly evil from a code-review standpoint,
mainly because of this implicit conversion. Implicit conversions are usually considered
pretty evil, and they are more evil when they are converting to common or primitive types
like `int` or `std::string`.

In C++11 we can change it slightly:

```
  operator std::string() && {
    return ss.str();
  }
```

Now the conversion will only trigger when the `string_formatter` is an r-value reference.
So it's less likely to trigger, but it's also more complicated. Is it actually less evil?
Debatable.

Also worth mentioning: others have gone to even more elaborate hacks to get this to work
without a `string_formatter` shim: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6094/a-version-of-operator-that-returns-ostringstream-instead-of-ostream

No implicit conversions here, but we are overloading operators on standard library types which is usually a no-no.

---

Let's back up a bit. Why can't I compromise and do this? It's at least a little more compact:

```
if (num_doggies > num_biscuits) {
  std::ostringstream ss;
  log_warn((ss << "There are " << num_doggies" << " puppy dogs and only " << num_biscuits << " biscuits!").str());
  this->negotiate_biscuit_reduction();
}
```

It turns out that this doesn't compile, because `std::ostringstream::operator <<` returns `std::ostream &` and not
`std::ostringstream &`. By the time all the `<<` have resolved, we only have an `ostream &` so we can't use `.str()`.

My question is, why is that the case?

Why doesn't `std::ostringstream::operator <<` return `std::ostringstream &`? Is it:

- Undesirable for technical or safety reasons
- Adding unnecessary difficulty for standard library implementors
- Legacy -- it was always this way and changing it now might break code. (However, exactly what code would be broken by this? Since `std::ostringstream &` can be converted to `std::ostream &` by a standard conversion because of inheritance relationship?)
- Obscurity -- no one cares!

Note: I'm well aware of different ways to design `string_formatter` and logger classes. I'm specifically interested in whether there are design reasons in the standard library that make it much better for `std::ostringstream` to return `std::ostream &`.

Comment: You can trivially add a `.str()` to `string_formatter`, no?

Comment: @T.C. Yeah but that's not really the point, I'm more interested if there's some good reason I don't understand why `std::ostringstream` needs to return `std::ostream &`

Comment: Because there is no operator<< in ostringstream? It uses basic ostream one by magic of inheritance.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: Presumably, we could just add one, which does the same thing and returns the right reference type, right? The question is, is it actually extremely difficult to implement, or likely to break code, for reasons I don't understand now? I'm not an expert on streams at all.

Comment: @ChrisBeck - sure, it would be possible to provide a wrapper function for **every** inserter for **every** ostream type. That would also mean that user-written streams would have to provide wrappers for every inserter, and that user-written stream inserters would have to provide wrappers for every ostream type. Personally, I'd rather just write one inserter that works everywhere than N inserters that work for all flavors of ostreams except the ones that I forgot about.

Comment: @ChrisBeck, I am sure there are many ways to use `std::ostringstream` and `log_warn` that are not three liners and don't rely on implicit conversion. If you can accomplish that, do you care what the `operator<<` functions return?

Comment: I suppose one could say that `ostream&`-taking, `ostream&`-returning `operator<<`s are customization points and then provide global adaptors on top for concrete streams, similar to how `operator<<` works for rvalue streams. Such a design comes with significant extra complexity and doesn't seem very useful. `(os << a << b).stuff()` isn't exactly pretty or elegant; if for some reason you have to squeeze that into one line, `os << a << b, os.stuff()` with the comma operator works just fine and is about as ugly.

Comment: Some good answers in this comment thread, thanks much folks

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your post whether you would care what the `operato<<` functions return if you can simplify your code that deals with logging the warning messages.

Here's one way you can simplify the code that logs warning messages.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

void log_warn(std::string const& s)
{
   std::cout << s;
}

struct log_warning_impl
{
  mutable std::ostringstream ss;

  ~log_warning_impl()
  {
     log_warn(ss.str());
  }
};

template <typename T>
log_warning_impl const& operator<<(log_warning_impl const& l, const T & t)
{
   l.ss << t;
   return l;
}

log_warning_impl const& operator<<(log_warning_impl const& l, std::ostream&(*f)(std::ostream&))
{
   l.ss << f;
   return l;
}


#define WARNING_LOGGER log_warning_impl{}

int main()
{
   WARNING_LOGGER << "There is a problem in the " << 10 << "-th line of the data file" << std::endl;
}
```

In your case, you can simply use:

```
if (num_doggies > num_biscuits)
{
   WARNING_LOGGER << "There are " << num_doggies << " puppy dogs and only " << num_biscuits << " biscuits!";
}
```